# make javascript change select option by data-id reference

Tags: javascript, html

According to I have list option as the code and I want to create a javascript to select it refer by data-id
Example I want to make data-value="AFG" selected, how can i do?

```
<div class="choices__list choices__list--dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
<input type="text" class="choices__input choices__input--cloned" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-label="false" placeholder="">
<div class="choices__list" role="listbox">
<div id="choices--p_nationality-1o-item-choice-1" class="choices__item choices__item--choice is-selected choices__placeholder choices__item--selectable is-highlighted" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="1" data-value="" data-select-text="ກົດເລືອກ" data-choice-selectable="" aria-selected="true"></div>
<div id="choices--p_nationality-1o-item-choice-2" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="2" data-value="AFG" data-select-text="ກົດເລືອກ" data-choice-selectable="">Afghanistan</div>
<div id="choices--p_nationality-1o-item-choice-3" class="choices__item choices__item--choice choices__item--selectable" role="option" data-choice="" data-id="3" data-value="ALA" data-select-text="ກົດເລືອກ" data-choice-selectable="">Åland Islands</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want to create a list of dropdown options. You should be using a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element with nested `<options>`. Also, the `<select>` element has a default role of listbox. To select one of the dropdown options from it's custom [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and make it selected, you can target `HTMLElement.dataset.someAttr` to grab those values from the DOM.

```js
const listbox = document.querySelector(".dropdown");

for (var i = 0; i < listbox.length; i++) {
  if (listbox[i].dataset.id === "1") {
    listbox[i].selected = true;
  }
}

console.log(`data-id: ${listbox[0].dataset.id}`);
console.log(`data-val: ${listbox[0].dataset.val}`);
console.log(`selected: ${listbox[0].selected}`);
```

```html
<select class="dropdown" size="2">
  <option data-id="1" value="AFG" data-val="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
  <option data-id="2" value="ALA" data-val="ALA">Åland Islands</option>
</select>
```